# TFS alert weekly summary

Tags: tfs

we just migrate from SVN to TFS. What I'm looking for, is something like weekly summary alert. We had it in SVN, that every Sunday it send a mail with summary of all changesets, that was made last week.

Is there something similar? Or I need to use TFS API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in the box, you will either have to look for some 3rd party tool that does this, or write your own against the API / `tf history` command line output.